# Jbehave or just Selenium webdriver and junit

Tags: jbehave

I have a very big problem to solve.can i know why jbehave is important than selenium web driver+JUNIT? story written by jbehave can easily done using junit and webdriver.

/lahiruw

Comment: Where is that big problem?

Comment: Where did you read that ?

Comment: big prob is makky,i'm doing automation so recently my company told that they are hoping to move automation to jbehave. but i didn't see any important on that.but any way i'm learning jbehave tooo. what i'm asking from you'll is whats the difference between these two. ? its so easy to write automation using junit than writing stories.. :-(.

Comment: and i personally think we may have more stories+test cases when using jbehave.isnt it ,just asking to clarify ? :-(

Comment: JUnit is just a framework to run tests. JBehave is a framework for Behaviour-Driven Development (BDD)/Concordion is another option.

Comment: If you go with JBheave then you will need to write story and then actual test.

Comment: More information about BDD http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior-driven_development

Comment: hi makky , that means we can cover jbehave scenarios through junit+web driver as well ? isnt it so ? cos in jbehave we have lot of scenarios to cover.what i think is for one story(4,5 lines story) we need at least 3 to 5 java classes.but in other way we can cover a whole scenario using 3 java classes.am i wrong or misunderstood your answear makky ?

Comment: You have a Scenario and each scenario can have multiple stories.A scenario has 5 stories (e.g. 1-login ,2-click email ...).I would say have one test for each scenario.

Comment: Ah ok Makky tx a lot for the explanation :-) Have a nice day Ahead !

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to separate some concepts. 
JBehave is a framework that provides ways to run Acceptance Tests using stories that was written using Behavior Driven patterns. You can use it to execute acceptance tests against any kind of system, including Web with Selenium HQ.
With BDD the focus is on what your customer told you about what the system must do. So the main goal is clear communication !

So, off course you could use Junit + Selenium...  but your tests will be more technical.